# -use_wallclock_as_timestamps adds delay in live stream

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

We have a livestream (MPEG-TS with RTP), which we currently, for testing purposes, replay with `tcpreplay`.

Our mpeg-ts stream consists of 4 streams (codec details omitted for brevity).

```
Stream #0:2: Video: h264
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2
Stream #0:4: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Strean #0:3: Data: bin_data (FBID / 0x4494246)
Stream #0:0: Data: klv (KLVA / 0x41564C4B)
```

Sometimes the stream indexes are different (like audio stream being stream 0 and so on, I don't know if thats normal behavior)

What we currently try is just to get the stream and copy it with ffmpeg, like

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -hide_banner -i rtp://239.0.0.2:3000 -map 0 -codec copy -f rtp_mpegts rtp://239.0.0.1:2000`
```

This leads to the error `Application provided invalid, non monotonically incereasing dts to muxer in stream 0: [NUMBER] >= 0`

It always says `stream 0` no matter what stream 0 contains.

if I add `use_wallclock_as_timestamps` it works but adds a delay (compared to a video directly streamed from `239.0.0.2:3000` of ~10seconds which are never caught up.

If I set the output format to `mpegts` instead of `rpt_mpegts` it works as expected, the same I if don't map the KLVA and FBID stream.

Is this behavior expected (because of wallclock) or what can I do to either `use_wallclock_as_timestamps` without delay or get rid of the error above?

Comment: did you find any solution on this?

Comment: sorry, I forgot this comment.
Unfortunately I can't really remember and I switched projects.
I would have to check the code if you are still interested